# How to change div color from a given value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

```
<div id="nav">
    Some Text
</div>

<input type="text" id="color"><button onClick="changeColor()">Change</button>

<script>

    function changeColor(){

        var colorCode = document.getElementById('color').value;
        var  nav = document.getElementById('nav');

        nav.style.background = "'"+colorCode+"'";
    }

</script>
```

When i enter for ex.: red in the input field and than press the button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need those single quotes, just pass the value itself into the background attribute.

```
function changeColor(){

        var  nav = document.getElementById('nav');
        nav.style.background = document.querySelector("#color").value;
    }
```

Comment: Rebeka, Thank you very much.

Comment: @klmjiub if it's your answer please vote it and set and answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1.please refer to below code which should help you

```js
function changeColor() {
        var colorCode = document.getElementById('color').value;
        var nav = document.getElementById('nav');

        nav.style.background = colorCode;
    }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
        Some Text
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="color"><button onClick="changeColor()">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

change 
`nav.style.background = "'"+colorCode+"'";`
to 
`nav.style.background = colorCode;`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="nav">
    Some Text
</div>

<input type="text" id="color"><button onClick="changeColor()">Change</button>

<script>

    function changeColor(){

        var colorCode = document.getElementById('color').value;
        var nav = document.getElementById('nav');

        nav.style.backgroundColor = colorCode;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work. Sir check.

```js
function changeColor(){

        var colorCode = document.getElementById('color').value;
       document.getElementById("nav").style.color = '#'+colorCode;
    }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    Some Text
</div>

<input type="text" id="color" maxlength ="6"><button onClick="changeColor()">Change</button>
```

Comment: These are the sample color you can test it. You add your desired color also. 323e32 , 254033

Answer (score 0):

Try this this will work:

function changeColor(){

```
var colorCode = document.getElementById('color').value;
 $("#nav").css('background', colorCode);
   }
```